# How do I get the change from the same quarter in the previous year in a pandas datatable grouped by more than 1 column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datatable that looks like this (but with more than 1 country and many more years worth of data):

```
| Country       | Year | Quarter | Amount |
-------------------------------------------
| UK            | 2014 | 1       | 200    |
| UK            | 2014 | 2       | 250    |
| UK            | 2014 | 3       | 200    |
| UK            | 2014 | 4       | 150    |
| UK            | 2015 | 1       | 230    |
| UK            | 2015 | 2       | 200    |
| UK            | 2015 | 3       | 200    |
| UK            | 2015 | 4       | 160    |
-------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the change for each row from the same quarter in the previous year. So for the first 4 rows in the example the change would be null (because there is no previous data for that quarter). For 2015 quarter 1, the difference would be 30 (because quarter 1 for the previous year is 200, so 230 - 200 = 30). So the data table I'm trying to get is:

```
| Country       | Year | Quarter | Amount | Change |
---------------------------------------------------|
| UK            | 2014 | 1       | 200    | NaN    |
| UK            | 2014 | 2       | 250    | NaN    |
| UK            | 2014 | 3       | 200    | NaN    |
| UK            | 2014 | 4       | 150    | NaN    |
| UK            | 2015 | 1       | 230    | 30     |
| UK            | 2015 | 2       | 200    | -50    |
| UK            | 2015 | 3       | 200    | 0      |
| UK            | 2015 | 4       | 160    | 10     |
---------------------------------------------------|
```

From looking at other questions I've tried using the `.diff()` method but I'm not quite sure how to get it to do what I want (or if I'll actually need to do something more brute force to work this out), e.g. I've tried:

`df.groupby(by=["Country", "Year", "Quarter"]).sum().diff().head(10)`

This yields the difference from the previous row in the table as a whole though, rather than the difference from the same quarter for the previous year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the change over Country and quarter and not the year, you have to remove the year from the group.

```
df['Change'] = df.groupby(['Country', 'Quarter']).Amount.diff()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after, thanks! I think I'd over complicated what I was actually trying to do rather than taking a step back and reconsidering the grouping.

Comment: Happens to the best ;). Glad I could help.